# C enum declarations: Is there overlap of enumerated types based on the length of the word (32 or 64 bit) if there are too many types?

Tags: c, enums

I'm going through a tutorial on programming in C and I'm reading about the "enum" declaration.

It gives an example of using enum for determining multiple flags of styles of text.

https://www.programiz.com/c-programming/c-enumeration

It points out that using the bit wise OR operator "|" is a means of determining in one word what the combined styles of the text may be.

My question is, wouldn't there be overlap if this was the only way to combine style flags if there were too many flags that were being used in the enumeration?

For instance, if I only have an 8 bit computer and I put out an enum declaration like

```
enum exampleFlag {
        style1 = 1
        style2 = 2
        style3 = 4
        style4 = 8
        style5 = 16
        style6 = 32
        style7 = 64
        style8 = 128
        style9 = 255
};
    int main() {
        int myDesign = style9 | style1; 

            //    00000001
            //  | 11111111
            //  ___________
            //    11111111

        printf("%d", myDesign);

        return 0;
    }
```

OUTPUT

```
255
```

And then I want to check what the style is for the text but then style9 is the equivalent for all the styles being valid at the same time, so then...doesn't this cause a problem?

The tutorial isn't going to go all the way in depth but I wanted to ask this question since it seems to me that the way this works would cause overlaps of styles if the numbers were not chosen well while declaring the enumeration.

But maybe I am misunderstanding how the enum declaration really works.

Comment: With 8 bits, you could only have 8 flags.  If you want more, then use a wider type.  Even on an 8-bit CPU, the compiler should be able to create wider types by allocating multiple bytes to the variable.

Comment: What is the point of `style9 | style 1`? The `style9` already includes all the flags. `enum` does not care about the other definitions...there can even be two the same.

Comment: "if I only have an 8 bit computer and I put out an enum declaration like". But as a smart programmer you would not do that. Even if you had a 1000 bit type if you have 1001 flags then it wouldn't work. So 8 bits is not special - just need to work within the constraints of the type and system.

Comment: `enum` uses the `int` type, so you have as many flags as the size of the `int` which is never less than 16-bits.

Comment: ok good. that's what i was thinking and wanted to be sure about it. the next question would be, Is it possible to have 8 flags in an 8 bit computer that would still overlap like this and give you false positives because of two flags combining as a single flag?

Comment: So this would also give false positives if ever any flag could be summed up by the other flags? For instance, If I were to remove style9 entirely and change style8 = 48. This would cause the same overlap problem and give a false positive when checking for what style the text may have. Correct?

Comment: Essentially every value of every flag must not be able to be summed by any combination of the other flags which means some sort of "prime" quality that each flag has to be distinctly separate from the others in order to apply the bitwise OR operator to check for combined styles. Correct?

Comment: Normally, you assign each flag a unique power of 2, so that each one has exactly one bit set, distinct from all of the others.

Comment: Yes thank you for the confirmation. I think I understand what is going on with the enum declaration now. Just 1 small step towards understanding the bigger picture.

Answer (score 0):

From the comments, I was able to confirm my suspicions about the enum declaration.

In order to not have any overlap given whatever length of the word which is used by the architecture (32 bit or 64 bit or any other bit) you may not declare more flags than there are bits in the word length. Also, each flag in the enumeration must be included in the range of 2^n where n ranges from 0 to the length of the word (32 bit or 64 bit).

This enumeration is only necessary so long as you expect to use a single variable to store multiple flags through the use of the bit wise OR operator "|". Since the bit wise OR operator will only be able to distinguish between unique states that cannot be derived through adding them together, as shown in the original question.

This is useful in having styles for text such as bold, italics and underlined. In one variable you can determine whether it has one or any of these styles so long as their enumeration follows the pattern of 2^n for each style.

The enum declaration by default however does not permit a variable to store anything but a single flag at a time because of this overlapping issue that might occur through their numerical equivalent. However it is possible to store up to "n" number of states which corresponds to the length of the word of the architecture as previously stated within a single variable if you follow the pattern for that usage.

Answer (score 0):

Each bit can only have one of two possible values: 0 or 1. If you use bits as distinct on/off "flags", then each flag needs a dedicated bit, i.e., you cannot have more flags than you have bits. This applies universally, regardless of the programming language.

However, this doesn't mean that your machine's word size limits the number of flags you can have: you can just use more than one word (e.g., on a 32-bit machine you could have an array of 32-bit integers that you access like `flags[n / 32] & (1 << (n % 32))`). Of course this means additional overhead and the flags become harder to pass around.

Meanwhile I think it is relatively uncommon to have a large number of related but independent flags. If the flags aren't all related to the same thing, they should be stored separately (e.g., `style_flags` and `state_flags`).

And if the flags aren't mutually exclusive, you perhaps you should enumerate the different combinations instead, in which case instead of *n* flags you have 2<sup>*n*</sup> different cases. For example, instead of flags like `bold`, `light` and `semibold`, you could have `weight` as a number, or `style` as an enumerated set of cases).